# Why is Qt for Python so painfully slow even with a small table?

Tags: python, sql-server, qt, pyqt5

I'm working with Qt for Python. I provide below a minimal example. The first file is automatically generated via Qt designer and pyuic5, I simply added a tableView to the main window. The second file, I programmed it. I am connecting to a SQL Server database using a QSqlQueryModel and connecting this model to a tableView. The queried table has only 22 rows and 4 columns. Doing anything at all on the GUI is painfully slow. Scrolling or clicking on a table element takes about 4 seconds to respond. Why is this? Am I using Qt wrong?

File generated using Qt designer and pyuic5 (saved as example.py):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'example.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 50, 551, 411))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My file:

```
import example
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQueryModel, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
import sys

class window(example.Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(MainWindow)
        
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC', 'DGCR')
        db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=**add server name here**;DATABASE=DGCR;Trusted_Connection=Yes;")
        
        db.open()
        
        q = """SELECT *
                FROM dbo.table"""
            
        model = QSqlQueryModel()
        model.setQuery(q, db)
        model.fetchMore()
        
        self.tableView.setModel(model)
        
        
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = window(MainWindow)
    
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't use ODBC so I can't reproduce your problem (with sqlite your code works fine). But I can suggest you 3 unrelated things: 1. always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (also for basic examples) which you can easily add in [designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html); 2. do not subclass the form class but instead inherit from *both* the main Qt class *and* the form class, so you just need to create an instance of your main class and do everything from there: `class window(QMainWindow, example.Ui_MainWindow):`; 3. classes should have capitalized names, variables not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @musicamante. Can you expand on the double inheritance? What is the benefit of this?

Comment: It seems from your pyuic5 file that you are using a very old version of qt5/pyqt5 (5.9.2). Are you able to test using the [latest version from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/)?

Comment: @RicardoCorralesBarquero the real benefit comes from using a class for the actuall Qt widget, which simplifies things and allows the possibility of overriding functions (specifically, event handlers). The benefit of *also* inheriting from the UI class (not *only*) is that, since that class is fundamentally used only for setting up the ui, it is almost useless after that step, but integrating it in the "joined" subclass keeps the object structure more consistent. You could of course use the single Qt widget inheritance and create an `ui` object for the form class, but that won't give you real->

Comment: @RicardoCorralesBarquero ->benefits, and you can only access to ui element through that `ui` object. You can read more on the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). The other alternative is to completely avoid the multiple inheritance, only subclass the Qt widget (QMainWindow in this case) and use `loadUi` from the uic module (`uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)`), which allows you to directly load the `.ui` file and set up the ui with it, which has practically the same effect of the multiple inheritance approach.